# how to open a executable file from pendrive?

Tags: linux, blender

I am trying to open blender 2.79 dev build, but I get a dialog saying `Failed to execute child process “/mnt/sdc1/MBD-Stuff/blender-2.79/blender” (No such file or directory)`.

I tried another stable build and it opened, but I do not understand why the another did not do anything, or show the dialog.

I am using fatdog 64 800 os.

Comment: Add the output of `ldd /mnt/sdc1/MBD-Stuff/blender-2.79/blender` please. You're probably missing some required libraries.

Comment: @muru add the output of ldd? what do u mean?

Comment: @muru there are a few screens

Comment: https://scontent-mia3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.15752-9/62216534_2180076772090911_1609309209130696704_n.jpg?_nc_cat=104&_nc_ht=scontent-mia3-1.xx&oh=2b0bd088ac3547e49e2f68efa2300a9c&oe=5D8D0D25

Comment: https://scontent-mia3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.15752-9/61911473_2371532552901548_7516854132834041856_n.jpg?_nc_cat=107&_nc_ht=scontent-mia3-1.xx&oh=7dd35e112a22c0891440a93d5629fb77&oe=5D90F266

Comment: If file really EXIST and after specifying absolute path for execution, if you get message such as `"Failed to execute child process “/mnt/sdc1/MBD-Stuff/blender-2.79/blender” (No such file or directory)"`, it means that you either trying to execute 64-bit executable on 32-bit arch or vice versa.

Comment: @SHW but its a 32 bits program :/

Comment: Please add output of `findmnt -T /mnt/sdc1/MBD-Stuff/blender-2.79/`.

Comment: Please show output of `ls -lF /mnt/sdc1/MBD-Stuff/blender-2.79/` and `file /mnt/sdc1/MBD-Stuff/blender-2.79/*` and state which of these file is the one used to run the program.

Comment: I cannot see the output of `ldd` in your question. @muru asked you to perform the following command on the terminal:
`ldd /mnt/sdc1/MBD-Stuff/blender-2.79/blender`

Please update your question with the output.

Comment: @thecarpy there is above the screenshot showing that i executed the comand

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor i am not getting what you want to i do with that comand

Comment: https://scontent-mia3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.15752-9/62064378_2275455022570917_8404164298531667968_n.jpg?_nc_cat=105&_nc_ht=scontent-mia3-1.xx&oh=cf698fe74f5d4e746454790bbd2217fd&oe=5D82FEBF

Comment: Open an interactive bash, and type the command. Then paste the result into the question.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor already tried that, that is what appears, see the recent screenshot above this comment

Comment: Please paste text as text. It is easier to read, and we don't want to know about your hair, your dinner, or electric sheep.

Comment: Also add output of `pwd` (in same session), and the other things requested.

Comment: what do you mean with "output"... pwd where goes?